# Why in some models the Friedman rule is not optimal?

Tags: monetary-policy, friedman

I want to know why in some models the Friedman rule stops being optimal. For example, in some models like MIU or CIA, where usually you don't have leisure, the Friedman rule is optimal. But in other models with bonds (for example) the Friedman rule stops being optimal because it breaks some non arbitrage conditions.